# Launching and waiting a GUI app to finish with Python

Tags: python, user-interface, subprocess

I need to launch a GUI application, wait for the application to quit, and then start the other processes.

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/open", "-a", "/Applications/Mou.app", "p.py"])
print "Finished"
... start the other processes
```

However, the process returns right away without waiting for the Mou.app to finish. 
How can I make the python process to wait? I use Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the `open` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html), the `-W` flag causes `open`  to wait until the app exits.

Therefore try:

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/open", "-a", "-W", "/Applications/Mou.app", "p.py"])
print "Finished"
```